# The adjective colère with en

Tags: adjectifs

I am studying adjectives now. I am puzzled by the adjective **colère** (angry) because I see it used with the preposition **en**. Which of these is the correct way to translate, *an angry woman*?

> une femme colère ou une femme en colère

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*[Colère](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/col%C3%A8re)* is not an adjective in everyday French (at least in France), it's a noun. It means *anger*, not *angry*.

There is no adjective with exactly the same usage as *angry*. What comes closest is the phrase *en colère* (literally: in a state of anger). Another adjective that's often used in everyday life is *[énervé](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/%C3%A9nerv%C3%A9)*, but its meaning is a little different, leaning more towards *nervous*, especially in literary use (in colloquial speech, *énervé* does mean *angry*).

The adjective *colère* has fallen into disuse, and means *prone to anger* (as opposed to angry right now). Nowadays, we would say *[colérique](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/col%C3%A9rique)* or *[coléreux](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/col%C3%A9reux)*.

Protesters sometimes use “en colère” to say they're angry about a particular social issue. (I think the [French Federation of angry bikers](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/F%C3%A9d%C3%A9ration_fran%C3%A7aise_des_motards_en_col%C3%A8re) popularized this formulation.) They would not describe themselves as *colères* (quick-tempered); *en colère* here suggests rightful wrath.

Comment: Isn't *fâché* roughly the same as *angry*?

Comment: @Jez Roughly, but not exactly. *Fâché* usually means angry with a specific person, or sometimes with a specific issue. It can be at an intellectual rather than emotional level. *En colère* is emotional, and you can be *en colère* (or *énervé*) due to an accumulation of unrelated minor irritations.

Answer (score 6):

> une femme en colère

is the standard translation for *an angry woman*.

[Reference](http://www.wordreference.com/enfr/angry)

The other form is rarely used (as [confirmed by the ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%C3%AAtre%20col%C3%A8re,%C3%AAtre%20en%20col%C3%A8re&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=7&smoothing=3))

Answer (score 5):

You can say both but the first one is old:

> 1. Adjt. Pop. et vieilli. Prompt à s'irriter ; d'un caractère violent. Un homme colère. Des enfants colères. Par méton. Il est d'humeur colère.

from *[Dictionnaire de l'Académie](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie9/col%C3%A8re)*

> II.− Emploi adj.
>
> A.− [En parlant d'une pers.] Que son caractère porte à se mettre facilement en colère :
>
> 1. Je me suis aperçu depuis longtemps que les gens colères soutiennent toujours qu'ils ne sont pas colères, que ceux qui ont peur, disent souvent qu'ils n'ont pas peur; ... Napoléon Ier, Lettres à Joséphine,1806, p. 119.

*[source](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/col%C3%A8re)*

Answer (score 4):

- *colère* is a noun that means *anger*
- *être en colère* means *to be angry*
- *se mettre en colère* means *to get angry*
- *mettre quelqu'un en colère* means *to make somebody angry*